# Общий член ряда Тейлора

Tags: математика, ряды

Никак не получается найти общую формулу для вычисления n элементов. Нашел зависимость Un = x^(2*n) / 2n!, но к сожалению она не подходит к первому элементу.

[image: формула]

Comment: Подходит-подходит!

Comment: Только знак вы забыли

Comment: Тут как бы принято задавая вопросы по математике делать вид, что они имеют хоть какое-то отношение к программированию: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3030/%D0%9E-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B5

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что он не относится к программированию.

Answer (score 2):

Не тянет на ответ, но как вставить в комментарий формулу?...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Только вы спросили, как лучше держать микроскоп при забивании гвоздей, а не как забить гвоздь. Мне так кажется...

Если вы начнете при программировании вычислять каждый член по общей формуле - значит, мне не кажется :)

**Намек:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да вы правы. Я не совсем понял алгоритм вычисления этой функции. Нужно получить рекуррентную формулу чтобы получить следующий ряд члена через предыдущий. Я просто не понимаю как найти эту рекуррентную формулу для данного ряда.

Comment: Я напишу. U(2n+2)=-u(2n)*x*x/(2n+1)(2n+2)

Comment: См. намек в обновленном ответе.

Answer (score 0):

Она подходит, потому что 0! считается равным 1, а x^0=1.
И умноженное на (-1)^n.

```
U(2n+2)=-u(2n)*x*x/(2n+1)(2n+2)
```